# AWS, migrate Sql Server to MySql, from one region to another

Tags: mysql, sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-dms

I have a RDS sql server db running on aws ireland and a RDS mysql db running on aws paris.

I want to migrate data from one place to the other using Database Migration Service.

I read I could achieve this with a VPC peering connection across regions.

Is there another way to do this? 
Via S3 bucket for example?

Comment: any particular reason you don't want to use the migration service ?

Comment: I didn't know if it was the right thing to do when you have a cross region migration. It seems to be the simplest way and the cheapest one, right?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to create a snapshot of your RDS instance and copy it to your desired region.  Upon having created the snapshot in your destined region, restore the RDS instance from your snapshot. 

Refer the link to create a snapshot [Creating a DB Snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreateSnapshot.html)

Refer link to copy snapshot [Copy a DB snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CopySnapshot.html)

Restore a DB snapshot[Restoring a DB snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Tutorials.RestoringFromSnapshot.html)